# How do I transform this Paypal curl request into an ajax or angular request?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, curl, paypal

I have a Paypal request done in curl. However, I want to use AngularJS to send this request. How do I rewrite this request in AngularJS ? Or could I just use curl inside my AngularJS request ? If so, how ?

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-d "{
"sender_batch_header": {
    "email_subject": "You have a payment"
},
"items": [
    {
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {
            "value": 12.34,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "receiver": "shirt-supplier-one@mail.com",
        "note": "Payment for recent T-Shirt delivery",
        "sender_item_id": "A123"
    }
]
}"
```

Here is the link to my jsfiddle.net/dv9v4t61/4

Comment: Can this not be easily figured out using the documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I could not . That s why I asked.

Comment: Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: Passing nested variables/parameters to my url post request

Comment: *That* would make a much better question than a generic "how to rewrite this" - questions of that type (which often look like mere coding requests) tend to be badly received

Comment: In your curl example I think what looks like nested parameters is actually just a string that happens to contain JSON. You could try just sending a string with the data in Angular, too. (I don't know the platform so I can't give a definitive answer)

Comment: @Pekka웃 here is a JS Fiddle for my code : https://jsfiddle.net/dv9v4t61/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99335/discussion-between-moussa-sarr-and-pekka-).